# Jolt transformation of json - how to add shift operation for null value

Tags: json, transformation, jolt

I have three scenario which are:

**Scenario 1:** When `"testInt" == 10` then `"isTrue"` should be set to `false` and `"testInt"` to `0` and `"testString"` as it is.

*Input*

```
{
"testString" :"testValue",
"testInt": 10,
"isTrue": true
}
```

*Expected output*

```
{
"testString" :"testValue",
"testInt": 0,
"isTrue": false
}
```

**Scenario 2:** When `"testInt" == null` then `"testInt"` should be removed and others as it is.

*Input*

```
{
"testString" :"testValue",
"testInt": null,
"isTrue": true
}
```

*Expected output*

```
{
"testString" :"testValue",
"isTrue": true
}
```

**Scenario 3:** When `"testInt" != 10`(also `not null`) then no changes.

*Input*

```
{
"testString" :"testValue",
"testInt": 20,
"isTrue": true
}
```

*Expected output*

```
{
"testString" :"testValue",
"testInt": 20,
"isTrue": true
}
```

It will be helpful if someone suggest me how to achieve these through jolt **shift** operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define such a `shift` operation along with `default` operation in order to be able to handle `null` cases through `"null"` to `null` conversion

```
[{
"operation": "default",
"spec": {
    "testInt": "null"
}
},{
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
        "testString": "testString",
        "testInt": {
            "10": {
                "#0": "testInt"
            },
            "null": null,
            "*": {
                "@(2,testInt)": "testInt"
            }

        },
        "isTrue": {
            "@(2,testInt)": {
                "10": {
                    "#false": "isTrue"
                },
                "*": {
                    "@(3,isTrue)": "isTrue"
                }
            }
        }

    }
}]
```

where `@(integer,key)` such as `"@(2,testInt)"` or `"@(3,isTrue)"` representing the level going up to start search for the needed key presented as the second argument. That can be calculated by counting opening curly braces after `"spec": {` except for this first `{` within `"spec": {`.

Comment: Thanks @barbaros-Özhan for your response, but in scenario 2 I'm not getting output what I expected. I'm getting only    {"testString" : "testValue"}  in this "isTrue" is getting dropped.

Comment: I'm struggling with this issue because in my case I'm getting null instead of "null". I didn't find any solution to handle null, is that not possible in jolt shift operation?

Comment: @VikramKumar I've added a null conversion through the default operation. Good luck.

Comment: again Thanks for your quick reply but one limitation is also there which is if any field is null then it should be removed. That is in scenario 2.

Comment: yes, right @VikramKumar , just a slight change is needed `"*": "null"` -> `"testInt": "null"` within the default spec.

Comment: Thanks alot @barbaros-Özhan , finally I'm getting expected output.